# Qlikview - arrayList

Tags: date, qlikview

i need to calculate difference between two date excluding sunday. I have table with dates and i need to calculate number of dates of repeated days from last date.

if i have dates like that

```
27-05-2017
29-05-2017
30-05-2017
```

I use this code in script

```
date(max(Date)) as dateMax,
date(min(Date)) as dateMin
```

And i get min date = 27-05-2017 and max date = 30-05-2017 then i use in expressions

```
=floor(((dateMax - dateMin)+1)/7)*6 + mod((dateMax - dateMin)+1,7)
+ if(Weekday(dateMin) + mod((dateMax - dateMin)+1,7) < 7, 0, -1)
```

And get result 3 days. Thats OK, but the problem is if I have next dates:

```
10-05-2017
11-05-2017
27-05-2017
29-05-2017
30-05-2017
```

When use previously code I get min date = 10-05-2017 and max date = 30-05-2017 and result 18, but this is not OK.

I need to count only dates from

```
27-05-2017
29-05-2017
30-05-2017
```

I need to get max date and go throw loop repeated dates and if have brake to see is that date sunday if yes then step that date and continue to count repeated dates and if i again have break and if not sunday than close loop and remember number of days.

In my case instead of 18 days i need to get 3 days.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you creating a master calendar in the script where you can apply weights or any other rule to your days. Then in your table or app you can just loop through the dates or perform operations and sum their weights (0: if sunday, 1: if not). Let's see an example:

```
// In this case I'll do a master calendar of the present year

LET vMinDate = Num(MakeDate(year(today()),1,1));
LET vMaxDate = Num(MakeDate(year(today()),12,31));


Calendar_tmp:
LOAD
$(vMinDate) + Iterno() - 1 as Num,
Date($(vMinDate) + Iterno() - 1) as Date_tmp
AUTOGENERATE 1 WHILE $(vMinDate) + Iterno() - 1 <= $(vMaxDate);


Master_Calendar:
LOAD
       Date_tmp AS Date,
       Week(Date_tmp) as Week,
       Year(Date_tmp) as Year,
       Capitalize(Month(Date_tmp)) as Month,
       Day(Date_tmp) as Day,
       WeekDay(Date_tmp) as WeekDay,
       if(WeekDay = '7',0,1) as DayWeight //HERE IS WHERE YOU COULD DEFINE A VARIABLE TO DIRECTLY COUNT THE DAY IF IT IS NOT SUNDAY
       'T' & ceil(num(Month(Date_tmp))/3)  as Quarter,
       'T' & ceil(num(Month(Date_tmp))/3) & '-' & right(year(Date_tmp),2) as QuarterYear,
       date(monthStart(Date_tmp),'MMMM-YYYY') as MonthYear,
       date(monthstart(Date_tmp),'MMM-YY') as MonthYear2      
RESIDENT Calendar_tmp
ORDER BY Date_tmp ASC;

DROP Table Calendar_tmp;
```